# Exit method in case of API error and continue with other methods

Tags: ruby, api

Is it possible to raise an exception if any, when calling an API, then exit the method in which exception happened and continue normally calling other methods? For example in case like this:

```
Class1.first_method
Class2.second_method -> failed because of an API error
Clas3.third_method - I want this one to continue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class1.first_method

begin
  Class2.second_method
rescue StandardError => e 
  $stderr << "An error occurred: #{e.message}"
end

Clas3.third_method
```

This is an example of a rescue block, which is part of the way ruby permits [Exception handling](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html)